# How to remove space after a colon in CSS with Sublime Text 3?

Tags: sublimetext3, css-editor

This question is about editing css files in Sublime Text 3, with use of autocompletion.

I want this:

```
.class { color: #FFF; text-align: center; text-decoration: underline }
```

to be this:

```
.class { color:#FFF; text-align:center; text-decoration:underline }
```

as I type, not post-processor plugins.

Comment: It is `color` not `text-color`. You need to modify, or create, a completions file. (I always have the space myself.)

Comment: Yes, it's color. I was thinking about `text-align` and `color` at the same time.
So, you have a solution about this?

Comment: Investigate the use of completions, and completions-files, in Sublime Text. There isn't a simple 'one sentence' answer to this question, you need to research. Creating individual snippets is an alternative route. ST is not a *hold my hand* IDE, it can be highly customized but requires effort.

Comment: Did you search for any insight into how to do this? What in the results you found fell short of what you need?

Comment: Of course I searched. I found a lot of solutions on how to do this on Sublime Text 2, but not 3. On Sublime Text 3, .py files are compressed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, let me say that I'm against this for readability reasons - if you want to minify your CSS, there are [plenty of tools](https://sublime.wbond.net/search/minify%20css) available to do that within Sublime. That being said, there is a way to do it, but it requires some effort. First, make sure you have [Package Control](https://sublime.wbond.net/installation) installed. Next, we'll need to extract a file from a `.sublime-package` file, so install the [`PackageResourceViewer`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/PackageResourceViewer) plugin. To do that, once you have Package Control installed and have restarted Sublime, open the Command Palette with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> (<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> on OS X) and type ***`pci`*** into the prompt to bring up the **`Package Control: Install Package`** option. Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, wait for the repositories to load, then type ***`packresview`*** to bring up the **`PackageResourceViewer`** option. Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> again, and wait for it to install.

Next, open the Command Palette again, and type ***`prv`*** to bring up the **`PackageResourceViewer`** options, then select **`PackageResourceViewer: Open Resource`**. Scroll down to **`CSS`**, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, then scroll down to **`css_completions.py`** and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> again to open it. You can ignore 99% of the file, just scroll down to line 190, which looks like this:

```py
                l.append((p, p + ": "))
```

Just delete the space after the colon `:` like so:

```py
                l.append((p, p + ":"))
```

save the file, and you should be all set. You may want to restart Sublime (and reopen all your CSS files) for the full changes to take effect.

Comment: Thanks, it's working! I understand your point. This is the way I'm writing code for years now - http://zalog.ro/css/layout.css I think it's a little strange to keep that space, but I'll think about it :)