# Remove space after colon in Sublime Text 4

Tags: css, autocomplete, sublimetext, sublimetext4

The previous solution was listed here: [How to remove space after a colon in CSS with Sublime Text 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23711469/how-to-remove-space-after-a-colon-in-css-with-sublime-text-3)

I have Package Control installed and PackageResourceViewer.

However the updated `css_completions.py` file is larger than the previous solution and quite different.

The part of code in the new version that looks to control the auto insert space after colon starts on line 870

```
        if matches:
            colon, space, value, term = matches.groups()
            if colon:
                # don't append anything if the next character is a colon
                suffix = ""
            elif value:
                # only append colon if value already exists
                suffix = ":" if space else ": "
            elif term == ";":
                # ommit semicolon if rule is already terminated
                suffix = ": $0"
```

However no changes through here seem to work. Is there another way to remove the auto insert after css declaration?

Comment: What changes to the new code did you try?

Comment: Changed: `suffix = ":" if space else ": "' --> 'suffix = ":" if space else ":"`
And also tried: `suffix = ": $0"`